# Reduce calls of DBI::common::Fetch (Perl)

Tags: mysql, perl, profiling, dbi

I have been trying to reduce the runtime of a program I've created.

I used a Profiler, which told me that 63% of the time was spent was on DB::st::execute. I then ran a DBI Profiler, and found which of my calls were taking the longest:

```
+ 1 SELECT Gene FROM genotypegene WHERE Genotype like ?
= 754 0.163602352142334 0 0 0.0156009197235107 1332756184.24322 1332756184.74384
```

I changed the amount of calls from 754 down to 14:

```
+ 1 SELECT Gene FROM genotypegene WHERE Genotype like ?
= 14 0.00399994850158691 0 0 0.00100016593933105 1332923220.99416 1332923221.70477
```

The program speed hasn't increased significantly however, and my profiler now says that 100% is spent on DBI::common::FETCH. I'm not sure what method this is referring to.

Before I edited my program to cut down the number of calls of 'SELECT Gene', it said DBI::common::FETCH was taking 0.000003 sec/call, whereas now it is taking 4.467... sec/call. Why would DBI::common::FETCH now be taking so much longer sec/call than previously? ( The only other thing I have noticed between the two profiles is that the original profile had a call to  which the new profile no longer has. If I look at the Profile as the program is running, it only has one call to  but this increases in time as the program runs)

Thanks!

Edit: Here is the table I am selecting from (put in here for easier reading than in the comment part) :

```
CREATE TABLE genotypegene
(
Genotype VARCHAR(20),
Gene VARCHAR(20),
FOREIGN KEY (Genotype) REFERENCES genotype(Genotype),
FOREIGN KEY (Gene) REFERENCES gene(Gene)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Edit 2:

The fields for the DBI Profile are here: http://metacpan.org/pod/DBI::Profile#Report-Format

The reason I was able to go from 700~ to 14 is because of my inexperience as a programmer (self taught, only started using perl 3 months ago). I was originally calling the information from the database every time I needed it (so was calling the same information more than once). Once I saw that this was slowing the program down I changed it so it called the information I needed at the start of the program then stored it in a hash. I was then expecting this to speed the program up, which it has, but not as much as expected. This is why I was surprised at the 4.4secs for the DBI::common::Fetch as it was never this slow before, and to my knowledge I didn't change anything in the program that should make this call this slow

This is the [Devel Profile](http://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aProfile) for the program once edited:

```
%Time    Sec.     #calls   sec/call  F  name
100.00 386198925.3409  86442494   4.467698     DBI::common::FETCH
 0.00 15263.1450  21928855   0.000696     DBI::st::execute
```

(many other functions listed too, just selected the ones of interest)

and here it is before it was edited:

```
%Time    Sec.     #calls   sec/call  F  name
65.01 8767.3435  21766318   0.000403     DBI::st::execute
2.29  309.2408  86510899   0.000004     DBI::common::FETCH
11.52 1554.1823        0  1554.182323  *  <other>
```

(discrepancy between 65% and 63% is because this is a different run of the program than the one I mentioned at the start, but it is roughly the same)

Comment: What is your database schema for this table. your database queries might be taking a lot of time.

Comment: For that particular call: 
CREATE TABLE genotypegene
(
Genotype VARCHAR(20),
Gene VARCHAR(20),
FOREIGN KEY (Genotype) REFERENCES genotype(Genotype),
FOREIGN KEY (Gene) REFERENCES gene(Gene)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
Although I do have other tables in the database that I also fetch & input information into during the running of the program (edited this post as I originally copied wrong table in)

Comment: I do not see GENOTYPE column in your table schema ?

Comment: Apologies, I originally copied in the wrong table

Comment: Are you running the same query many times or all these all different queries? If it's the first, you can do some local caching if you don't expect the data to change?

Comment: Thanks, it's actually different queries each time

Comment: Try using [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::NYTProf) to get a more complete picture of where time is being spent.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing your database design, I would suggest 2 things based on your queries.

i) You are using LIKE queries to match strings, so create a INDEX on your GENOTYPE column, that will give performance boost.

ii) Try using MyIsam engine, and a FULL TEXT engine on GENOTYPE column , based on what kind of matches you are doing on your column strings.

Are your queries like:

a) `SELECT Gene FROM genotypegene WHERE Genotype like 'YYY%'  (starts with )`

or

b) `SELECT Gene FROM genotypegene WHERE Genotype like '%YY%'  (contains )`

Please share an exact query, that would help more.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think Myisam supports foreign keys? Here is the query: foreach my $genekey (keys %$Genotype){ $sth4->execute($genekey) - Where $genekey would be something like 'Genotype1'.

Comment: An index is not a foreign key. DhruvPathak is simply pointing out that depending on what you like contains an index may improve the situation. If your like strings start with % is is likely the index cannot be used but if they have some chrs before the % the index could be used and it would be faster. Also your example of a genekey is daft as it it a plain string 'Genotype1' so why even use like?

Comment: I know that an index isn't a foreign key, but my table (see above) does have foreign keys linking it to other tables. The reason I use 'like' is because I connect to the database varying number of times each program runs, depending what 'genekeys' are contained within the Genotype hash. It runs through all the genekeys in the Genotype hash e.g could run 'Genotype1', followed by 'Genotype4' in one run, and in another run 'Genotype5' followed by 'Genotype6' followed by 'Genotype8'

Comment: or do you mean that I should use '=' instead of like? Would that make it faster?

Comment: Your only giving us part of the information. 63% of 1 millionth of a second for instance would suggest you are flogging a dead horse. What are the fields for those numbers from the DBI profiler. How did you change your code to go from 700 odd selects to 14 e.g., are you doing less selects but fetching more rows. FETCH is used in DBI to retrieve an attribute from the DBI itself or the DBD. I doubt it takes 4s to retrieve a value from a tied hash so that is questionable. Try and make your problem smaller and more complete and we may be able to help better.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post with the info you require. I'm not really sure how to make the problem smaller, as I think the real issue is that I don't understand why it is 4secs rather than the 0.00003 it was before

Comment: I will add that this call didn't seem to be taking 4 secs: I have a program that I run on a loop 5000 times, and each run of the program was taking less than 4 secs (the profile is the accumulation of the 5000 runs, rather than just 1 run)